# Server Error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when i use datepicker on nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a problem with the package **"@persian-tools/persian-mobile-datepicker"** in NextJs

the problem is **Server Error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "****",
  "version": "0.*.*",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.1",
    "@persian-tools/persian-mobile-datepicker": "^0.0.13",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
    "framer-motion": "10.12.16",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility": "^0.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-dropdown-select": "^4.9.3",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-simple-star-rating": "^5.1.7",
    "react-tabs": "6.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "swiper": "^8.4.5",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I used dynamic import but didn't work!
I added "type": "module" in package.json but it didn't work too.
And I also changed "target" and "module" in tsconfig.json from "target": "es6" to "target": "es2021" or "esnext" and changed "module" from "esnext" to "commonjs" with ts-node like this:

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext"
  }
```

anybody knows what is the problem?

Comment: It might be related to ECMASCRIPT version. An import statement added at ES6 version, but I think you are using ES5. Are you using const moduleName = require("moduleName") statement in your code?

Comment: No, I'm using ES6

Comment: Would you please write your package.json, node version and tsconfig.json

Comment: You can check now

Comment: I think during the treating problem Some of settings are entangled. Then it causes the problem.

Comment: @persian-tools/persian-mobile-datepicker library works on nextjs boiler-plate. tsconfig.json of mine is almost same as yours except target : es5. And It is my next.config.js /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work yet